# Understanding a terminology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology

When a textbook says if a property holds "Outside a compact subset", does it mean the property holds outside any compact subset or a particular compact set?

> If $X$ is a locally compact hausdorff and $K \subset U \subset X$ where K is compact and $U$ is open, then there exists a continuous function from $X$ to $[0,1]$ such that $f=1$ on $K$ and $f=0$ outside a compact subset of U.

Does this mean $f=0$ on $U-K$ or on $U-\cup K_\alpha$, $K_\alpha$ is a compact subset of U, I guess since the statement says "a compact subset" I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It obviously will not be on $U-K$. There is some larger compact subset $K’\subset U$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, saying a property holds "outside a compact subset of ..." means there is a compact subset $C$ of ... such that the property holds for all points of $X\setminus C$.

In your particular case, it means there is a compact $C\subseteq U$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X\setminus C$.  As $f=1$ on $K$, we necessarily have $K\subseteq C\subseteq U$.